# How to speed up my new system

Tags: windows-7, memory, performance

I have just bought a desktop, since I already have an ultrabook laptop, for what I do which is a lot of gaming (for my YouTube channel), video editing, web/graphics design stuff and normal internet browsing.

With my new desktop I have noticed when it is rendering a video it does lag a bit when opening the Chrome browser. It takes around about 30 seconds to open while the video is being rendered, so I am wondering what needs to be upgraded in order to make it run smoothly.

When multitasking too much it does freeze for a few seconds here and there or lag, but during normal browsing there's no lag unless I'm opening more than five tabs and browsing fast.

Here are my specs:

Case: Casecom CF341
OS: Windows 7 64 Bit
Motherboard:  Asus P8B75-M LX
CPU: Intel Pentium CPU 2030 3.00GHZ
RAM: 2GB (it says 1.68GB is usable)
Graphics: OnBoard Intel HD Graphics (I can add a gaming or other graphics in a slot)

What would I need to upgrade to make it lag free and to be able to do gaming and video editing without lagging.

Comment: `I have just bought a desktop, since I already have an ultrabook laptop, for what I do which is a lot of gaming (for my YouTube channel), video editing, web/graphics design stuff and normal internet browsing.` It’s not clear which system you are using for what. Are you saying that you bought the desktop to do gaming, video-editing, web-design, and web-browsing? Or are you saying that you do those tasks on the laptop? (The comma after *laptop* would indicate the latter, but it’s better to be sure.)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your financial situation I would do the following:

1. Upgrade RAM to at least 4GB (preferably 8GB)
2. Buy a dedicated graphics card.

If you are going to do Video Editing this will make you life a whole lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

A solid state HDD wouldn't hurt, most these day harddrives are a bigger bottleneck than most people realize.

Comment: A solid state drive for your operating system. That will speed up boot time as well as the main applications you use. Use a normal hard drive (7200rpm is good) for storage of your video editing content.

Answer (score 1):

Solid state devices (SSD and adding more RAM, 8GB total RAM if possible) will give your computer a performance boost. A graphics card will improve performance and also protect your investment in your new computer, because then if a hardware device ever fails, it will probably be the graphics card instead of the CPU or the motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

There is room for improvement when it comes to RAM.

Most games will require from 500 MB to 1 GB of usage, while another 500 MB will probably be used for other applications running in the background. The reason that you see high loading times while rendering is because Chrome is probably being loaded in the page file (in the hard drive), and because the rendering is using about 75% of the CPU.

If you're doing other stuff while rendering, you'll want to consider getting 4 GB or even 8 GB of RAM. Once you upgrade a specific thing, you most likely will not need to upgrade again in the future.

As an example, here's how much memory my computer is using right now:

[image: http://i.imm.io/1lzfT.png]

In addition, I like to use 2 GB as a RAM disk for storing temporary files.

Comment: I might be upgrading to the full GB hoping in A couple of months

Answer (score 0):

## Problem Determination

> With my new desktop I have noticed when it is rendering a video it does lag a bit when opening the Chrome browser. It takes around about 30 seconds to open while the video is being rendered, so I am wondering what needs to be upgraded in order to make it run smoothly.

To be fair, Chrome *always* takes a while to load. It takes only a few seconds to show the main window, but then it loads all of the user data like history files, most-visited pages lists, extensions, etc. which can take several more seconds to completely load depending on your hardware, how many extensions you have installed, and how long you’ve been using that Chrome profile.

If you have a lot of Chrome extensions installed, then your first step is to disable, or even uninstall, as many as possible (remove any you never use, and disable you only use rarely).

> When multitasking too much it does freeze for a few seconds here and there or lag, but during normal browsing there's no lag unless I'm opening more than five tabs and browsing fast.

## Problem Analysis

You said it doesn’t lag when you open tabs, but you have not said how fast Chrome *starts up*. Assuming that Chrome starts up quickly when you are not rendering a video, then we will proceed with the analysis.

> Here are my specs:
>   RAM: 2GB (it says 1.68GB is usable)
>   Graphics: OnBoard Intel HD Graphics (I can add a gaming or other graphics in a slot)
>
> when it is rendering a video it does lag a bit

And there’s your problem. You have not specified what programs you use and exactly what kind of video-rendering you do, but it probably doesn’t matter. The lag is because you don’t have enough memory.

## Technical Explanation

### Memory Exhaustion

Video-rendering is a fairly resource-hungry process. It will usually eat up not only a lot of CPU time, but also a lot of memory. What is almost certainly happening is that your video-editor is allocating a fairly large amount of memory to do its work, but because you only have 1.68GB of memory (of which Windows 7 itself uses at least a couple of hundred megabytes), there is very little left for anything else. Worse, Chrome is a big memory-hog and even a fresh install with no extensions, showing only a single `about:blank` page will use up at least 100MB.

### Virtual Memory

Because of this lack of physical memory, Windows resorts to [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Memory). Virtual memory is “emulated/simulated” memory using the disk-drive instead of actual RAM. What happens is that Windows “swaps” out memory of programs that are inactive by copying their allocated memory to the disk, thus freeing up physical memory for other things to use. When the program becomes active again, it pushes something else out to disk and copies the program’s data back into physical memory. Because disk-drives are *much* slower than physical RAM, this process is quite slow.

### Observations/Tests

If you look at the disk-activity light while you are in this situation (a video being rendered in the background), if you start Chrome, you will see that the HDD LED flashes a lot. It is normal for it to flicker for a couple of seconds while Chrome reads its data files, but you are probably going to see it turn on and stay solid for quite a while. This is because Windows is swapping memory around to accommodate Chrome’s memory allocation.

Even opening a new tab can take a while because Chrome wants even more memory which again, requires “borrowing” from other programs.

## Resolution Advice

> What would I need to upgrade to make it lag free and to be able to do gaming and video editing without lagging.

### Memory

Your best bet is to simply upgrade the memory. For years now, RAM has been cheap enough that it has been touted as the most inexpensive way to upgrade, and that remains true today. This is particularly true if you have very little RAM.

### Video Card

In addition, the reason that you are seeing only 1.68GB of your 2GB of memory being available is because your Intel HD Graphics adapter is, as it says, *onboard*. That means it is built into the motherboard, and thus it does not have its own video-memory like a standalone video-card would, instead it “shares” memory with the system. You currently have it configured to use 384MB of video-memory which actually comes out of your 2GB of system-memory.

You could get a standalone video-card with dedicated memory to save that 384MB, but just getting actual RAM would be much cheaper and give you even more than just 384MB. That said, depending on your budget, you may still want to consider a dedicated video-card *in addition to more RAM*. That’s because a newer, dedicated video-adapter would have better functionality and more power. Depending on the one you pick, it may actually help with video-rendering, and probably also give better performance with your games.

Comment: Thanks everyone ;.)
I added another 2GB of ram that I found lying around the house its actually stopped the lag and the system can do anything including rendering videos with no lag. 

All I need todo now is upgrade the graphics card and maybe at another 4GB of ram for gaming.

I'm considering upgrading to A SSD in A couple of months.
Thanks Again :)

Comment: Told ’ya. `:-D` But seriously, it’s nice that it works now. I had only a couple of “gig” of RAM until this year, but then I also used XP most of the time. Doing heavier stuff like that will definitely benefit from more RAM. You may want to look into *how much* benefit you might see from an SSD before spending money on it. (Also consider getting a cheap one from the local classifieds as a test before getting a new, expensive one.)

Comment: I wouldnt mind adding 16gb :)